# icons not placing side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I want to place 2 icons side by side on any screen size. It works properly on medium devices, but when I run it on mobile devices the icons are placed one below other and not side by side. Also, my margins are not working on smaller devices.

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6 xs-my-20 col-md-6">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 xs-my-20 col-md-6">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the classes of the two divs containing the icons to col-6 if you always want two columns

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `col-xs-6` like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And if you upgrade to bootstrap V4 simply do this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if xs-my-20 is a custom class you have created but you should be able to add col-xs-6 and it will allow the two icons to be displayed side by side in any size screen.

if xs-my-20 is a custom class you may have some css that is affecting display such as margins etc.

You also don't need to add col-md-6. If you use col-xs-6 it will include xs and above (xs,sm,md,lg). as with all col sizes. for example col-md-6 already applies col-md-6 and col-lg-6 without you having to write it.

Hope this helped.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icons"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```